# How to fetch PDF file from a folder inside an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, java-io, aws-java-sdk

I am new to AWS and S3 with Java I want to fetch an object from the s3 bucket which is a pdf file that is inside of a folder in the bucket. I have successfully fetched the file from s3 bucket, but I am getting `file not found exception` while trying to get the file from a folder.

Here is my code-

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Fetching pdf from aws s3");

        String bucket = "my-bucket";
        String key = "65/65-abc.pdf";
        AmazonS3 amazonS3 = getAmazonS3Client();

        S3Object object = amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, key));
        InputStream ins = object.getObjectContent();

        try {
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(ins);
            //Saving the document
            doc.save(key);
            System.out.println("PDF created");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    private static AmazonS3 getAmazonS3Client(){
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("myAccessKey", "mySecretKey");
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2).build();
    }
```

Output-

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: 65\65-abc.pdf (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

My S3 bucket structure is like -

```
my-bucket/65/65-abc.pdf
```

`my-bucket` = is the bucket name
`65` = is a folder name
`65-abc.pdf` = is the file name

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?  It really looks like `doc.save(key);` is failing because you don't have a local folder `65`, not any failure with S3.

Answer (score 0):

Assume I have a PDF in a folder like this:

[image]

I can easily get this PDF using the [Transfer Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-amazon-s3-transfer-manager-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/?sc_channel=sm&sc_campaign=Developer_Blog&sc_publisher=TWITTER&sc_country=SDK&sc_geo=GLOBAL&sc_outcome=awareness&trk=na_TWITTER) - part of the **[AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)**.

YOu are using a very old Java API which is no longer considered best practice. AMazon strongly recommends using V2 over V1.

Now here is the [code](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/transfermanager/GetObject.java) that works fine for this use case.

```
package com.example.transfermanager;

import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.FileDownload;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.S3TransferManager;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * To run this AWS code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your AWS credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class GetObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "  <bucketName> <objectKey> <objectPath> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "  bucketName - the Amazon S3 bucket to upload an object into.\n" +
                "  objectKey - the object to download (for example, book.pdf).\n" +
                "  objectPath - the path where the file is written (for example, C:/AWS/book2.pdf). \n\n" ;

    

        long MB = 1024;
        String bucketName =  "<MyBucket>";  //args[0];
        String objectKey =  "foo/foo2/book.pdf" ; //args[1];
        String objectPath =  "C:/AWS/bookhuge39.pdf" ; //args[2];

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3TransferManager transferManager =  S3TransferManager.builder()
                .s3ClientConfiguration(cfg ->cfg.region(region)
                        .targetThroughputInGbps(20.0)
                        .minimumPartSizeInBytes(10 * MB))
                .build();

        downloadObjectTM(transferManager, bucketName,  objectKey, objectPath);
        System.out.println("Object was successfully downloaded using the Transfer Manager.");
        transferManager.close();
    }

    public static void downloadObjectTM(S3TransferManager transferManager, String  bucketName, String objectKey, String objectPath ) {
        FileDownload download =
                transferManager.downloadFile(d -> d.getObjectRequest(g -> g.bucket(bucketName).key(objectKey))
                        .destination(Paths.get(objectPath)));
        download.completionFuture().join();

    }
}
```